# Missing something in If statement argument

Tags: javascript

Why is this code doesn't execute the statement within the if() statement?

Page has two input fields and a button. The code is:

```
var n = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("password").value;


    document.getElementById("button").onclick=function(){

        if(n=='abc' && p=='abc') alert('Welcome  '+n);
        else 
        alert('Enter the correct credentials');
        };
```

Always the alert after the else is displayed even if i enter the values abc&abc.

Comment: Can you please add your HTML code as well ?

Comment: place debugger inside onclick function and see it in console

Comment: You need to retrieve the values at the time of the click, not while the page is loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your text box values are empty when variables are assigned values. So while comparing with 'abc' they return false.

```
var button1 = document.getElementById('button');

button1.onclick = function() {
var n = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("password").value;

        if(n=='abc' && p=='abc') alert('Welcome  '+n);
        else 
        alert('Enter the correct credentials');

}
```

This code checks for the value of text field after button is clicked and hence works as expected. Please refer to fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/5HHkZ/

Comment: If this solved your problem, would you mind accepting this as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the script is executed, `#user` and `#password` inputs are empty, so `n` and `p` variables are empty too. 
When you do `var n = document.getElementById("user").value;`, you ***COPY*** the `#user` input value into your variable : this is not a reference. I mean that if input `#user` value changes, `var n` won't change.

So you just have to get your inputs values at the moment click event is triggered :

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick=function(){
    var n = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if(n=='abc' && p=='abc') alert('Welcome  '+n);
    else 
    alert('Enter the correct credentials');
};
```

Comment: Not accurate. The handler does know them, but their value will always be the same.